# lxc 2.0.0 failed to start after upgrading

Tags: upgrade, lxc

i have Ubuntu 14.04 and i installed lxc then 1.0.8 was installed. But i needed 2.0.x version hence i upgraded it using following commands.

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntu-lxc/daily
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install lxc
```

After the update when i want to start container there is error as shown below.

```
lxc-start: lxc_start.c: main: 344 The container failed to start.
lxc-start: lxc_start.c: main: 346 To get more details, run the container in foreground mode.
lxc-start: lxc_start.c: main: 348 Additional information can be obtained by setting the --logfile and --logpriority options.
```

My OS is up-to-date and upgraded.

Answer (score 1):

You should run:

`lxc-start -F -l DEBUG -n <container name>`

To find out the root cause of the issue.

In my particular case it was:

`Permission denied - could not access /var/lib/lxc.  Please grant it 'x' access, or add an ACL for the container root.`

Which was fixed by `chmod +x /var/lib/lxc`

Comment: I followed your suggestion but the following error was displayed.      root@avinash-OptiPlex-3020:/home/avinash# lxc-start -F -l DEBUG -n sairam
lxc-start: conf.c: instantiate_veth: 2595 failed to attach 'veth11IIJ7' to the bridge 'lxcbr0': Operation not permitted
lxc-start: conf.c: lxc_create_network: 2872 failed to create netdev
lxc-start: start.c: lxc_spawn: 1080 failed to create the network
lxc-start: start.c: __lxc_start: 1353 failed to spawn 'sairam'
lxc-start: lxc_start.c: main: 344 The container failed to start.
 Can you suggest something now

Comment: It looks like you've hit [bug #1406925](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/lxc/+bug/1406925), there's a fix there that you can try (adding `lxc.aa_allow_incomplete = 1`). Let me know if that works.

Comment: Error remians same but when I debuged it the following error was show         lxc-start: lxc_start.c: main: 295 Executing '/sbin/init' with no configuration file may crash the host

Comment: The initial error seems to be related to `lxcbr0`, it's either missing or you have something restricting access to it. Can you also check [bug #1240757](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/lxc/+bug/1240757) and [bug #1451232](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/lxc/+bug/1451232) ? If those don't fix it, can you send the output of `brctl show` ?